# Runlevel 0 script not running properly on shutdown

Tags: scripts, shutdown, runlevel

I have a basic script where all it does is delete a specific user on shutdown.  I made it executable and created a symlink to /etc/rc0.d/K99deleteuser so that it would actually run on shutdown.  Unfortunately, it only seems run every now and then in no discernible pattern.

The script

```
#!/bin/sh
deluser "username" --remove-all-files
rm /etc/rc0.d/K99deleteuser
```

All it is supposed to do is remove the user and then delete itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research, I have discovered a much more proper and reliable way of doing this.  First, you add an [LSB header](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) to your script that defines the runlevel settings you want to use and then put an executable version of the script in /etc/init.d.  After doing this, you can use the update-rc.d command to add the script to your desired runlevels.  Make sure that the settings you use with the LSB header and update-rc.d match or things will explode.